# Request in Jersey test returns 404

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-test-framework

Existing answers to this question haven't helped me - I'm running simple test against the root path of my application but I'm always getting 404 as a response status code. I'm running the application on Tomcat 9 and my configuration is in `web.xml`.

List of dependencies (I hope I haven't forgot something):

```
  <properties>
    <jersey2.version>2.28</jersey2.version>
    <jaxrs.version>2.1</jaxrs.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
      <version>${jaxrs.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-mvc-jsp</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

`web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>sigma-hotel-manager</display-name>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>jersey-servlet</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.sigma_hotel_manager</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.mvc.templateBasePath.jsp</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/views/</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
      <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.forwardOn404</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jersey-servlet</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The controller I'm trying to test:

```
package com.sigma_hotel_manager;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.Viewable;

@Path("/")
public class WelcomeController {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML+";charset=UTF-8")
    public Viewable getHome(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        request.setAttribute("title", "Sigma Hotel Manager");
        return new Viewable("/welcome/index");
    }

}
```

The actual test:

```
package com.sigma_hotel_manager;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.DeploymentContext;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.ServletDeploymentContext;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.spi.TestContainerException;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.spi.TestContainerFactory;
import org.junit.Test;

public class WelcomeControllerTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(WelcomeController.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected DeploymentContext configureDeployment() {
        return ServletDeploymentContext.builder(configure()).build();
    }

    @Override
    protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() throws TestContainerException {
        return new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory();
    }

    @Test
    public void getHomeIsSuccessful() {
        Response response = target("/").request().get();

        assertEquals("HTTP response should be 200: ", Status.OK.getStatusCode(), response.getStatus());
        assertEquals("HTTP content type should be: ", MediaType.TEXT_HTML, response.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE));
    }

}
```